# Can I use newer version of Jackson than bundled in Websphere 8.0?

Tags: java, jackson, websphere, classpath, websphere-8

I am developing an application under Websphere Application Server v8.0 and I need to use `org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl` and `org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl` version 1.9.2 (mandatory).

On WAS 8.0 such libraries are already included in his runtime, but his version is older. It's 1.6.2 (you can see it in these images):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTv4a.gif
and
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vs3TM.gif

I added 1.9.2 jars on the classpath, but the application uses libraries that are bundled in WAS (1.6.2), ignoring the ones in classpath.

Because of this, I can't use some jackson features in 1.9.2 version, that were not in 1.6.2.

My question is: Is possible to configure WAS to not use jackson from his own bundled jars, and let the application to use jars from classpath?

Answer (score 2):

To override the vrrsion provided by the server when called by your application, add the library to an "isolated shared library" then associate it with your app.

Comment: Would an isolated shared library override a WAS-Default library? Or would it better to use the 'PARENT_LAST' classloader configuration to achieve this?

Comment: It's what isolated shared libs are meant for. It is less likely than parent-last to break something else.